# How to add a keyword rule to bounce email for certain user on Exchange Online?

Tags: office-365, office-online

We are using Office 365 email for our business. Is it possible to set up a mail rule, such that:

- for any incoming email to a certain user, e.g. John Lee
- there is a
  keyword in the mail subject or body, e.g. Headhunt

the email will be bounced.